# UIImagePickerController stuck at compressing Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got the image picker working in a popover on the ipad, but when running in the simulator when I select a video in the picker it says its compressing and then gets stuck.

Nothing happens, the delegate function never gets called.

Comment: FWIW - I have exactly the same problem: The UIImagePickerController UI works fine, I can pick a video, I can play it, but when I click "Choose" it hangs with the "compressing video" progress bar stuck at the very beginning. I see a log message "setting movie path:" that looks like it comes from within Apple code. Don't see that on the device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687005/uiimagepickercontroller-stuck-on-compressing-video-on-ios10-simulator-after-choo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found one solution - it works on the physical device.  I dont know why it crashes on the simulator, but if I run the app on my Ipad it works fine.

Comment: a lot of the stuff with UIImagePickerController and other hardware specific classes (AddressBook ie) don't work on the simulator properly :)

Answer (score -1):

It's a late answer but you can fix it by following this procedure: go to the simulator hardware menu and select TV out: 640x480 after that try to run your app from xcode and then again go to the simulator hardware menu and select TV out: Disabled.