# UIImagePickerController: "choose/play" a video from the library does not work on iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an iPhone APP and testing it on the iPhone simulator/Xcode. I have a problem: UIImagePickerController: "choose/play" a video from the library does not work on the Simulator (but it works on the real phone). How to solve this problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you added the video to the simulator by dragging and dropping into it?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have put the video into the simulator. I found that some people have asked the same problem with the simulator: "The UIImagePickerController UI works fine, I can pick a video, I can play it, but when I click "Choose" it hangs with the "compressing video" progress bar stuck at the very beginning..."    Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025139/uiimagepickercontroller-stuck-at-compressing-video

Answer (score 0):

Check if the error: "Error creating aggregate audio device" occurs where the NSLogs are printed. If so, the fix is in the following thread:

[UIImagePickerController throws ERROR: 185: Error creating aggregate audio device: 'what' when trying to select video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746616/uiimagepickercontroller-throws-error-185-error-creating-aggregate-audio-device)

Comment: I've mentioned this fix so it might help somebody with a similar issue. It might or might not apply to the scenario where the simulator hangs during compression.