# UIImagePickerController stuck on compressing video on iOS10 simulator after choosing a video

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, xcode8

I had this app that always worked normally on iOS9, now I've migrated the swift code to 3.0 and added the required plist rows to get access to photos library.
While trying to pick a video (preloaded by dragging) from the camera roll using `UIImagePickerController`on simulator it always get stuck on "Compressing Video" and doesn't callback the delegate methods.

```
   @IBAction func videoFromLibrary(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    }
```

Using a real device it works fine, it really seems to be an Apple bug, I'm wondering if anyone had this issue or I'm missing something to make `UIImagePickerController` work again correctly using videos on simulator (or if there is a workaround).

Comment: Having the same issue, have you found any work around?

Comment: Unfortunately no... but I've opened a bug to Apple. I suggest you do the same https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3

Comment: For me this happens on real devices too. Looks like it happens only at the first time ever the app tries to get a video using the imagepickercontroller on iOS10. I tried multiple workarounds, but nothing is working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this same problem running it on the iPhone 7 Plus simulator but it seems to dismiss when I run it on an iPhone 6s Plus simulator. Maybe a bug in the simulator.

Comment: thank you adrielR, on iPhone 6 works. I really hope the will fix in the next xcode realease

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for iOS 10 for Xcode 8 and iPad Pro 12.9in Simulator.

If you use iPad Pro 9.7in Simulator then it works. Good god Apple, get your act straight!